# How to make my photos Creative Commons

Tags: legal, creative-commons

I need to post some photos to a competition and as a requirement, the rules say that they should be listed as Creative Commons.  Can someone tell me how could I make my photos Creative Commons?

Comment: Be carefull! If a competition is to win, with Creative commons you wil loose all rights to them. That sounds fishy.

Comment: You don't lose any rights to your photos. The copyright still belongs to you, and you can use them in any way you like. The Creative Commons licence just gives others the right to use them (with certain conditions, depending on what licence you release them as).

Comment: They should specify the EXACT licence(s) they intend you to use. Note, as others have indicate - you are giving away SOME rights in your photos. See the instructions link that Caleb has provided. The tightest CC licence is arguably Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives 4.0 International  which means ~~~ that others can copy and share your unmodified photo non-commercially if they attribute it to you. | Quite likely more likely they want at least  "Attribution-NoDerivatives 4.0 International" ~~ ANYONE can use your unmodified photo for ANY purpose (including sale) if they attribute it to you.

Comment: What is the competition? Link? | Note that SOME CC licences in a competition are a way for organisers (and anyone else) to get free permanent commercial access to your photos.

Answer (score 6):

> Can someone tell me how could I make my photos Creative Commons?

[Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org) is an organization that has created and maintains a number of different licenses for sharing content. They also have [a set of instructions](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/) for how to get started choosing a license and applying it to your work. You should also check the competition rules to find out exactly how they want you to indicate the license you've chosen and whether there are specific Creative Commons license features that they require.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different Creative Commons licenses, each one with its own specifics on how the photo can be used. If you are looking for a simple way to license your photos as Creative Commons you can create a [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/) account. When you upload the photos you can choose the license that you want, and then the license will be displayed on the page for each photo. Be su